# FatalErrorException syntax error, unexpected ''url'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => true
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => 'http://localhost',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => '31531513513513',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Super User level.
    | Specify at which level will the player have administrator access
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'sulevel' => '14',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Website name
    | Input the name of your server, the same name that will be provided in the website titles
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'webname' => 'Your Name Here',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => array(

        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\SHAHashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',

    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Service Provider Manifest
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service provider manifest is used by Laravel to lazy load service
    | providers which are not needed for each request, as well to keep a
    | list of all of the services. Here, you may set its storage spot.
    |
    */

    'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => array(

        'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Cache'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'ClassLoader'     => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
        'Config'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
        'Cookie'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Form'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
        'Hash'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'HTML'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
        'Input'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Lang'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Paginator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
        'Password'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Seeder'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
        'Session'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'SSH'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
        'Str'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
        'URL'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',

    ),

);
```

[image: http://prntscr.com/fff66n]

this is the error I've been trying for the past few days to fix it but I have no clue whats the error lol.It's really annoying and pissing me off could you guys watch over it and tell me whats wrong into the code?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma after the "debug" entry:

```
'debug' => true,
# Here --------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a comma after debug value.

```
'debug' => true,
```

Comment: Thanks but now I have so many errors: http://prntscr.com/fff79g  laravel is pain in the ass zzzz

Comment: You need to set a valid key `'key' => '31531513513513',` Which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: I have no idea, I'm trying to setup myself a panel which I got from a forum but its so... weird http://prntscr.com/fff93u   one error is fixed 30 more appear like WTF

Comment: You're using a very old version of laravel. You haven't even got the basic setup done to run the application. You should go back and read the instructions on how to setup and install the code you have.

Comment: Im just proceeding with the uninstall of it , thanks though.